# What is the best way to ignore null values in JSON data using Svelte?

Tags: json, null, svelte

I am making an app in Svelte using TheCocktailDB's API. When it comes to listing measurements and ingredients, the JSON data looks something like this:

```
strIngredient1  "Tequila"
strIngredient2  "Triple sec"
strIngredient3  "Lime juice"
strIngredient4  "Salt"
strIngredient5  null
strIngredient6  null
strIngredient7  null
```

...and so on, up to 15.

Is there a best way in Svelte to run code that displays each of the fields that contain a value and ignores those with a null value?

Comment: If the ingredients were not mixed in with all the other data, I would use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and then `.filter` on the resulting array. (That API is pretty bad.)

Comment: Agreed — it's so basic it's hard. :D

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice [tutorial I found on YouTube](https://youtu.be/6oDSwcZPbxA) for Svelte Kit using this API.  Basically you would want to map over the ingredients and measurements etc.  Then filter the result.

Assuming saving the result to a variable called `result`…

```js
const result = await (
  await fetch('https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php')
).json()

const ingredients = [...Array(15)]
  .map((_value, i) => {
    name: result.drinks[0][`strIngedient${i + 1}`],
    amount: result.drinks[0][`strMeasure${i + 1}`]
  }))
    .filter((ingredient) => ingredient.name)
```

Now if `ingredient.name` has a null value, it is filtered out of the array.

Now you *could* consume it like this in your template:

```html
{#each ingredients as ingredient}
  <--! Your markup here -->
  <p>Ingredient: {ingredient.name} {ingredient.amount}</p>
{/each}
```

Comment: Thanks! It was the filtering that I wasn't sure how to set up.

Just one thing: I don't know TypeScript. :P (I know, I know...I'll get there. Still learning.)

I will definitely check out that tutorial.

Comment: I hear ya!  The code above is js but he uses TS for the tutorial, yep.  If this answers your question and works, great!

Comment: Hope you don't mind a follow-up question, but I went through the tutorial you linked to just to see if I could get the code to work, even though I don't know any TypeScript. It's giving me an error that says "Binding element 'fetch' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7031)." I followed directions every step of the way in the tutorial and haven't had much luck finding an answer with Google. Do you have any suggestions, by chance?

Comment: `export async function load({ fetch }) {
  const drink: DrinkType = await (await fetch('index.json')).json();

  return {
   props: { drinkProp: drink }
  };
 }`

The squiggly line with the error happens at fetch.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably not 'a best way' but different aproaches to get and display the ingredients with a value and their amount. This would be an alternative to the already given [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/9294d41b7f93429d9b548b3b83d55da6?version=3.47.0)

```
<script>
    async function loadIngredients() {
        const response = await fetch('https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php')
        const result = await response.json()
        const drink = result.drinks[0]

        return Array.from({length:15}).reduce((ingredients, _, index) => {
            const ingredient = drink[`strIngredient${index+1}`]
            if(ingredient) {
                ingredients.push({
                    name: ingredient,
                    amount: drink[`strMeasure${index + 1}`]
                })
            }
            return ingredients
        },[])
    }
</script>

{#await loadIngredients() then ingredients}
<ul>
    {#each ingredients as ingredient}
        <li>{ingredient.name} - {ingredient.amount}</li>
    {/each}
</ul>
{/await}
```